# Session disable inactivity logout

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

My problem is that my users keep saying to me that the checkbox "stay logged in" doesn't work for them (cookies are set / they had a look into the browsers current cookies and found them).
Now I checked twice my code but I can't find any error.
Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['stay_logged_in']) == '1') { 
setcookie("anyusr",$username,time()+(3600*24*30)); //30 days
setcookie("anytoken",$securitytoken,time()+(3600*24*30)); //for checking
}
```

Are I'm missing something? Or should I add something?

**Additional Informations**

- The value of $_POST['stay_logged_in'] is set correctly (1)
- Users can close and reopen browser and stayed logged in (2)
- May the session expired earlier than expected? I don't use any "auto-logout" functions
- Only in logout.php sessions would be destroyed
- using apache2 on a linux debian server
- happens approx. after 30 mins up to 1 hour "inactivity" on site

Checking the sessions:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
```

And later I'm using this to check if session is valid

```
if ($_SESSION['anyusr'] != $meUser['username'] XOR
$_SESSION['anytoken'] != $meUser['superspecialneverguessedtoken']){
setcookie("anyusr","",time()-31536000);
setcookie("anytoken","",time()-31536000); 
session_unset();
session_destroy(); }
```

And my checkbox is here:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="stay_logged_in" name="stay_logged_in" value="1">
```

Thanks for any help.

For all others - here is my working solution:

```
if ((isset($_COOKIE['anyusr'])) && (isset($_COOKIE['anytoken']))) {
    $AnyUser = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['anyusr']);
    $AnyToken = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['anytoken']);
    $CookieUser = ''; // num_rows WHERE $AnyUser AND $AnyToken
        if ($CookieUser == 1) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['anyusr'] = $_COOKIE['anyusr'];
            $_SESSION['anytoken'] = $_COOKIE['anytoken'];
        } else {
            session_start();
            setcookie("anyusr","",time()-31536000);
            setcookie("anytoken","",time()-31536000);
            session_unset(); 
            session_destroy();
            // Later: Redirect to login
        }
}
```

Comment: You set cookies, but you never check cookies. Shouldn't you "auto-login" a user who isn't logged in but has a valid cookie set?

Comment: I thought if I check the session with the randomized string would be enough. Thanks for your quick comment.

Comment: But that's the problem, if you want a user to stay logged in 3 days later then session will probably have expired but the cookie will still be there (unless they've cleared it but that's the user's choice not yours).

Comment: Aah, okay thats sounds logic. I wanna try @trpx 's solution right now - thanks again :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to write this as a comment, but have to share it as an answer, because of less rep. So, here we go. In your code, you are checking, if the session is valid. But after 30 mins (or one hour) it gets destroyed by serversettings. So you have to check, if there are cookies set, too. If there is a cookie **OR** a session, you can check if user is valid. Something like this should help:

```
if (($_COOKIE['anyusr'] || $_SESSION['anyusr']) && ($_COOKIE['anytoken'] || $_SESSION['anytoken']))
{
    // check if user is valid
    // if valid, user is logged in
    // set your session variables with userdata again
}
```

Comment: Actually this does seem to attempt to solve the OP's problem so it should be an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @trpx - I thought it would be "enough" if I check the session variables. I'll edit my code and give you a checked answer later (and the "prooven answer" mark) if the problem is solved.